# compute the following limit of integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f_t(x) = t\sin(t||x|^2-1|)$ is functiona from $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ compute the following limit expression.

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{\Bbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}}f_t(x) \phi(x)dx $$

Where $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^n)$

More speficifically find one function $g(x) $ such that $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}}f_t(x) \phi(x)dx = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}}g(x) \phi(x)dx$$

I try to guess the result by taking limit directly on $f_t$ that is $\lim_{t\to \infty} f_t(x)$ but find it diverge ,and try to compute $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n\setminus 
\{0\}}f_t(x) \phi(x)dx$ by integration by part, but no good expression appear in the process.I guess something to do with Riemann Lebesgue lemma?

I have no idea how to compute it ,may be there is some technic to handle this type of problem?

Comment: have you heard about stationary phase approximation

Comment: I have heard about it but I haven't learnt it,thanks @Thomas

Comment: do you mean the only stationary phase point $\{0\}$ is eliminated hence the integral need to converge to zero?